# Solution to the Rotation Matrix -- Inverse

Tags: matrices

Find the inverse of the rotation matrix where $\theta$ is a fixed angle. Then use your result to solve the system $x=a \cos \theta-b\sin\theta$, $y=a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta$ for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

I'm just really not sure on where to begin with this. Do I need to use a determinant because it is a 2x2 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta  & - \sin\theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} $$

If the 2×2 matrix is a rotation, when you invert it you will get the inverse rotation. So you either do it the long way (with 2×2 matrix inversion) or the short way of negating $\theta$.

Comment: Okay, I've successfully found the inverse of my matrix, but now what am I supposed to do with the system of x and y?

Comment: @jerry2144 Now that you have the inverse matrix, just multiply both sides by it to solve for a and b in terms of x and y.

Comment: Did I mention the awkward but correct way of transposing the matrix to get the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What is the opposite operation of rotating a vector by $\theta$ in the anti-clockwise direction?